# return standalone value from constructor not object

Tags: javascript

While learning the mongoDB I notice one constructor returning string with prototype function. For example

Following code will generate a random string, first 4 letter from string contain timestamp and to get the time stamp it has the prototype function.

```
const id = new ObjectID()  // 5c8766f4bcd712911ab81eea

console.log(id.getTimestamp()) // will print the date
```

I was just working how it been done. I am trying to create the simple constructor in same way but it always return object. How can we make it to return single value instead of object with prototype function.

```
function getMyTime(){
 this.timestamp = new Date().getTime()
}

const timestamp = new getMyTime(); // should print timestamp 1552385374255
console.log(timestamp.printReadableDate()) // should print date Tue Mar 12 2019 15:39:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**Edited**

```
class GetTime {

 constructor(){
 this.time = new Date().getTime();
 }

    getActualDate(){

  }

  toString(){
   return this.time 
  }
}

const stamp = new GetTime();

console.log(stamp) // should be 1552472230797

console.log(stamp.getActualDate()) //should be Wed Mar 13 2019 15:47:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ObjectId` class used by MongoDB is ultimately the `ObjectId` class provided by [js-bson](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson). **This `ObjectId` class uses a facility provided by Node.js `util.inspect`** to get itself printed as a [string](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/f4b16d91e969508c6b77b7e1f7b62bc2bc37b126/lib/objectid.js#L407):

```
ObjectId.prototype[util.inspect.custom || 'inspect'] = ObjectId.prototype.toString;
```

What is going on there is that `js-bson` adds a method which has for name  either `util.inspect.custom` or `"inspect"`. The 2nd name is used for compatibility with Node versions prior to Node 6.6.0. In node, [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) uses [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args), which ultimately uses [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to determine how to print each object passed to `console.log`, and it is possible to [customize what `util.inspect` does](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects) by adding a method on the object that we want to customize. For Node versions prior to 6.6.0 the method must be named `"inspect"`, for later versions it must have for name the value of `util.inspect.custom`.

So you can take a page out of what `js-bson` does and implement your class with:

```
const util = require("util");

class GetTime {
  constructor(){
    this.time = new Date().getTime();
  }

  toString() {
    return this.time;
  }
}

GetTime.prototype[util.inspect.custom || 'inspect'] = GetTime.prototype.toString

const stamp = new GetTime();

console.log(stamp);
```

Or this syntax might be more palatable to you or the development tools you use. I have used some code documentation tools in the past that are definitely more at ease with the following:

```
const util = require("util");

class GetTime {
  constructor(){
    this.time = new Date().getTime();
  }

  toString() {
    return this.time;
  }

  [util.inspect.custom || "inspect"]() {
    return this.toString();
  }
}

const stamp = new GetTime();

console.log(stamp);
```

This syntax provides the same result as the earlier one, though there is an additional call.

**As I mentioned above, this trick works only in Node.** If I try passing an `ObjectId` object to `console.log` in Chrome, then Chrome does what it does with every other object: print the constructor name and the fields of the object. As far as I can tell, there's no cross-platform way to customize how `console.log` prints objects.

Comment: Awesome! I went Mongodb git repository to find out what exactly what magical happening there. Thanks for the answer you deserves the bounty man.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor returns an object *by definition*.

The [MongoDB JavaScript driver's `ObjectID` returns a "new ObjectID instance"](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ObjectID.html), not a string. But the `ObjectID` class also implements a [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method which returns a string representation of the `ObjectID` object instance.

Comment: I disagree with the terminology. A constructor specifically does not return anything. It initialises an object. It is a common mistake for someone to attempt to return something from a constructor.

Comment: @AndyG A constructor *can* return something. But the `new` operator ensures that it is always an object (but not necessarily an instance of the actual class it was used on).

Comment: @Carlos Click the link, there is an example.

Comment: @str in example above link show by using prototype method we show string representation of class. but the string representation does not have any further prototype method and in mongoDB example the constructor itself return string representation of class without using any prototype method

Comment: @Carlos Not sure whether I understand you correctly. "*the constructor itself return string*" no it does not. The constructor *always* returns an object. But the class (e.g. `ObjectID`) may define a `toString` method that returns a string representation of the object. The `toString` method "[is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)".

Comment: @str in example `toString` explicitly getting called but not in mongoDB ObjectID class. How can call it automatically when new instance of class is initiated?

Comment: @Carlos `toString` can–but does not have to–be called explicitly. "*How can call it automatically when new instance of class is initiated*" you can't. But when you do `console.log(someInstance)`, the `toString` method of `someInstance` is called.

Comment: @str it will be easier for me to understand it through practical example. I have updated my question with class example. what are the changes do I need to do on class to behave it like mongoDB class. sorry for bother and thank

Comment: @Carlos OK, `console.log` itself will not work but it works if you actually force it to be handled as a string. E.g. `console.log(''+stamp)`

Answer (score 0):

A constructor called with `new` always returns an object. Almost everything in javascript is an object, but some objects are treated differently, like Strings.

You can, however, "fool" the interpreter by extending one of the base object types:

```
class ObjectID extends String {
  constructor () {
    // Call String constructor with random hex
    super(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16))

    this.timestamp = Date.now()
  }

  getTimestamp () {
    return this.timestamp
  }
}

const id = new ObjectId() // { [String: '2fff78'] timestamp: 1552718634749 }
console.log(`Id is ${id}`) // "Id is 2fff78"
console.log(id.getTimestamp()) // 1552718634749
```

Note: this is a very bad idea.